# Filtrar por rango de fechas en panel de administracion de Django

Tags: python, django, panel-de-administracion, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

Me gustaría que me ayudaran para poder hacer búsquedas por rango de fechas en el panel de administración de Django. Django tiene el atributo date_hierarchy que se usa de la siguiente forma:

```
class SaleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
```

Pero no es lo que deseo, ya que quiero hacer una búsqueda entre una fecha de inicio y una fecha final en el propio panel de administración de Django, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias al enlace que me dio **Isabel Cristina Ruiz Buritica** pude dar solución a la pregunta.

Lo que se debe hacer es instalar el **paquete django-admin-rangefilter** usando el **comando pip:**

```
pip install django-admin-rangefilter
```

Una vez hecho esto se registra el paquete ya instalado dentro del **fichero settings.py** en **installed_apps:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rangefilter',
]
```

Posteriormente iríamos al **fichero admin.py** y hacemos las siguientes importaciones:

```
from rangefilter.filter import DateRangeFilter, DateTimeRangeFilter
```

Después declaramos la clase de la siguiente forma para que aparezca tal como deseamos en el **panel de administración de Django:**

```
class MiClaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("Campo1", "Campo2")
    list_filter = (('Fecha', DateRangeFilter),)
```

Usando la instrucción:

```
list_filter = (('Fecha', DateRangeFilter),)
```

Nos aseguramos que nos salga el filtro de fechas estableciendo un rango tal como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último registramos la clase en el mismo **fichero admin.py**:

```
admin.site.register(MiClase, MiClaseAdminAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

En este tutorial esta explicando como agregar otro filtro al django admin, muy bien explicado: https://www.dothedev.com/blog/django-admin-list_filter/

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Recuerda siempre agregar las partes importantes que contiene el enlace y luego adjuntarlo al final si gustas, las respuestas que son solo enlace son considerados de baja calidad porque en algún momento puede que ese post simplemente desaparezca y tu respuesta quedaría inservible. ;)

Comment: Gracias Isabel, voy a revisar el link y te digo

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/339663)

Comment: No habia caído en cuenta de que puede quedar inservible la respuesta! Muchas gracias @Israel-ICM y padaleiana por el feedback!!

Comment: Isabel tu respuesta me fue muy útil, muchas gracias